# How to remove several Active Connections established by Firefox in the background to seemingly some local API server

Tags: windows, networking, firefox, tcp

When I checked active connection on my Windows with `netstat -ab` command, I found that Firefox has established several active connections to this seemingly local API. It had the name of a software project I was involved with several years ago (replaced with xxx here) and I guess it's the leftover of what our team member had been installed on my system for testing. Here's a sample of those background connections:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61192        xxxapi:61193         ESTABLISHED
 [firefox.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61193        xxxapi:61192         ESTABLISHED
 [firefox.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61194        xxxapi:61195         ESTABLISHED
 [firefox.exe]
```

There are about 30 of them and ports numbers seem to be changing somewhat randomly each time. How can I remove, disable or uninstall those ports or at least prevent Firefox from making those connections? I don't think it'd be wise to just leave them like that.

Comment: You have in entry in your 'hosts' file mapping `xxxapi` to 127.0.0.1, which the 'team member' probably did to allow testing or debugging something(s) using a local process. `netstat` by default reverse-resolves the remote address but not the local one; add flag `-n` and you'll see the remote address is also 127.0.0.1 -- and both ends of each connection are actually the same firefox process i.e. it's connecting to itself. My 115esr, with only a few tabs active, has two such, and yes they use transient (random) ports. Connecting to firefox is unsafe only if firefox itself is unsafe.

Comment: If you really want to kill them, the only easy way I know is tcpview from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview . What damage if any this will do to firefox I don't know and am not willing to test.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, there mus have been some steps to make FF establish those connections. Is there a way to find out those steps and undo them permanently? It might have something to do with JSON REST API from what I recall. 
With tcpview I have to do it every time, right? If yes that can't be very helpful.